# Compile libssh with msvc for x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, libssh

First of all, I’m not an expert in build libraries from the source with cmake and all this stuff. But unfortunately I have to. I followed up the steps mention in the INSTALL document of the libssh and read a few archived mails but nothing helps me out. It sounds so easy on the web, but I didn’t bring it to work. Here is what I’ve done so far:

- Download source from (Version 0.7.5) from [libssh git](https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/?h=libssh-0.7.5)
- As mentioned in INSTALL file, download and install [cmake](http://www.cmake.org) (Version 3.9.1)
- As mentioned in INSTALL file, download and install [OpenSSL](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) (Version 1.0.2)
- Ignore zlib, because its optional

Everything is installed in the default paths. Now starts cmake-gui.exe and set source code to `…/src` folder and binaries to `…/build` folder, press ‘Configure’ button, with Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64. 
Now the first error is generated: `install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION`. Okay, checks make file which use variable `LIB_INSTALL_DIR` to set the path, in my case the path is empty. Add item to cmake-gui named `LIB_INSTALL_DIR` with path to `../build` dir.

Fine, configuration works, generate works, open project works. Try to build ‘ALL_BUILD’ ends up in `error:  C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config.h': No such file or directory`. Searched my whole disk for the file, nothing found. I believe cmake have to generate this file, guessing right? Or is this file missing? Hope someone can help me out! Or maybe have a link to an already compiled lib? Doesn’t understand why libssh doesn’t offers a download, x64 is quite normal today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial inspiration is often the right one, the missing config.h is normally generated by cmake.

If you using cmake-gui.exe, it expects an path to the source, heading is ‘Where is the source code:’. I thought this means the path to the source code files, which are located under `…/src`, but this is wrong. I need to the set the path to the root folder, in my case `…` and everything works like a charm.

Also need to change back to OpenSSL version 1.0.2, because somewhere around 30 function declarations has changed.